# Can i use Firebase to retrieve data in real time from an arbitrary rest endpoint

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to monitor data in real time from a non firebase rest endpoint?

For example i have access to an endpoint that tracks a vehicle's coordinates and speed and it is updated in real time. How should it be integrated with Firebase in order to work?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? What platform are you building on?

Comment: Im using Spring Framework 4+ (=Java) and im talking about a REST end point that serves Open Data to my application.

Comment: It's going to be really hard to answer you based upon the information provided. Try to provide more details about what you want to do, what you're using, and what you have tried.